# One Note for Mac Images not Showing

Tags: macos, microsoft, onenote

Now that One Note as come out for Mac I was trying it out but already have a problem in that all the images I insert do not render - I get just an outline and a red cross)

- Tried jpg / png
- Via Copy/Paste and insert option

This is the result

[image]

Am I doing something incorrect or perhaps have some setting I could change to fix this?

**Update:**

Now I tried something else. I when to the online version and insert the image there. Now the app keeps crashing trying to sync.

I think it's just to soon to start using this. It's sad because the notebook/sections/pages concept is really good in my opinion

Comment: How do you insert them? (with such a new tool, you might need to walk us through the steps you took to cause the bug to appear)

Comment: I tried via copy/paste and also the insert image option.

Comment: So, you open the app and just paste an image that's already on your clipboard?

Comment: @bmike that and also using the insert option. Both don't work

Comment: I was hoping to recreate your problem, but neither of my Office365 accounts even work with version 15 of one note (the first public release) so I'll pass on making a third MS account for now. Since it's an editor's pick on the MAS, I bet you'll get an answer before too long unless a bug fix arrives from MS before then.

Comment: Hmm, interesting, I can successfully import images in each of the ways that you've listed here.  I tried various sizes of images and can't replicate the issue that you're experiencing.

Comment: @nadyne that's strange, there are a lot of people with problems with this app. From what I can tell it might have something to do with the accounts we're using. I tryed a new account and it worked, then deleted all my notebooks and tried again on my account and had the same problem. http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_onenote-onenote_mac/onenote-for-mac-crashes-at-start/1661c315-b61b-4b36-a5b9-665d0621c05e